# How to align the x position of the dots in seaborn scatterplot to a nested bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter-plot

I am trying to plot a scatter plot on top of a bar plot using `sns.scatterplot()` and `df.plot(kind='bar')`; The figure turns out to be fine, but it would be even nicer if I can align each of the scatter points to its corresponding bar with an identical label.

[image: The current plot]

I have read the [document](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html#matplotlib.patches.Rectangle) on Rectangle of `matplotlib.pyplot` that it has a `get_x()` method that can "Return the left coordinate of the rectangle";

I wonder if there is a way for me to assign these coordinates to the scatter points that'd be plotted by seaborn?

### Code

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
fig.set_size_inches(9, 9)
fig.set_dpi(300)

bar_df.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)

ax2 = ax.twinx()

sns.scatterplot(data=line_df, ax=ax2)
```

### Dataframes

#### bar_df

| year | apple | banana | citrus | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 12 | 34 | 56 | 78 |
| 2025 | 12 | 34 | 56 | 78 |
| 2030 | 12 | 34 | 56 | 78 |
| 2035 | 12 | 34 | 56 | 78 |

#### line_df

| year | apple | banana | citrus | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 23 | 45 | 67 | 89 |
| 2025 | 23 | 45 | 67 | 89 |
| 2030 | 23 | 45 | 67 | 89 |
| 2035 | 23 | 45 | 67 | 89 |

It'd be really nice if I could make the points in the same vertical line as the bar with the same header;

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Sure! @JoshFriedlander

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sns.scatterplot` interprets the x-axis as numeric. As such, it doesn't align well with a bar plot, nor does it have a `dodge=` parameter.
You can use `sns.stripplot` instead.

Seaborn works easiest with its data in ["long form"](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data), which can be achieved via pandas `pd.melt`.

Here is some example code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

bar_df, line_df = pd.read_html('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73191315')
bar_df_long = bar_df.melt(id_vars='year', var_name='fruit', value_name='bar_value')
line_df_long = line_df.melt(id_vars='year', var_name='fruit', value_name='line_value')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(6,6), dpi=300)
sns.barplot(data=bar_df_long, x='year', y='bar_value', hue='fruit', dodge=True, ax=ax)

ax2 = ax.twinx()
sns.stripplot(data=line_df_long, x='year', y='line_value', hue='fruit', dodge=True, jitter=False,
              edgecolor='black', linewidth=1, ax=ax2)
ax2.legend_.remove() # remove the second legend

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: combining seaborn dodged bar plot with scatter plot]

Comment: I'm still wondering whether there would be a simpler way to convert a pandas dataframe to the format needed by StackOverflow's edit format.

Comment: Doesn't to_markdown work? Or maybe I'm not sure what you mean by "StackOverflow's edit format".

Comment: Ah. Ok. I just learned something new. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! (also for educating me about how to read dataframes from websites in a much more efficient way)